# How to update field through Ajax in Ruby on Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In my form I am trying to update the `exchange_rate` field when the user changes the `currency` select box.

**application.js**:

```
$("#invoice_currency").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/invoices/get_exchange_rate',
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

**invoices_controller.rb**:

```
def get_exchange_rate
  from = current_user.base_currency
  to = params[:currency]
  @exchange_rate = GoogleCurrency.get_exchange_rate(from, to)
end
```

**get_exchange_rate.js.erb**:

```
$('#invoice_exchange_rate').val('<%= @exchange_rate %>');
```

**google_currency.rb**:

```
module GoogleCurrency

  def self.get_exchange_rate(from, to)

    ....

  end

end
```

This isn't working yet because, for some reason, `params[:currency]` can't be evaluated dynamically through Ajax.

Can anybody tell me how it's done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX call is not passing in any data, so `params[:currency]` will be nil in the controller.

You should add some data to the AJAX call, e.g.:

```
$("#invoice_currency").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/invoices/get_exchange_rate',
      data: { currency: $(this).val() },
      dataType: 'script'
  })
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks a lot! I kind of had a hunch but didn't know the exact syntax.